# get/set on FloatVectorProperty subtype COLOR

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I have a `FloatVectorProperty` with the subtype `COLOR` laid out in my operator. I would like to user to be able to control it like normal, but to be able to set the value if the material already exists. I have tried using `Get/Set` methods, but they seem to freeze up the color. What I would like is if the material doesn't exist it sets the value to (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), if it does then it gets that color and sets the value to it, but still allows the user to control the color. Any ideas on how to do this?